# Execute method using onclick or ID?

Tags: java, android, events

Keeping things short and simple, which is better for managing android click events when working with buttons?

Assigning it to an ID in the XML Construct lines?

```
android:id="@+id/ButtonEventName"
```

and working with it by detecting press event via Java? 
*Taken from the login activity template based in android studio:*

```
Button mEmailSignInButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.email_sign_in_button);
mEmailSignInButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        attemptLogin();
    }
});
```

or assigning the button to an onclick method:

```
android:onClick="EventName"
```

the integrate Java side:

```
public void EventName(){}
```

Which is more effective and reliable and recommended when working with button events?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both methods have their good and bad sides. I don't know which one is more effective though.

1. Using id + `onClickListener` is more complex code, but it gives you opportunity to do run-time check for errors. In your example that would mean additional `null` check.
2. Second approach is much simpler to read, but if you don't have `EventName` method app will crash

I prefer second one because it is simpler, and it is always easier to follow logic and find errors in less code.

I also have to add that while first solution does provide means of avoiding app crash, at the end that does not matter too much because if `findViewById` returns `null` you basically have same buggy, code that is in mismatch with layout `xml` and adding `null` check (that should be superfluous in final working app) just additionally pollutes the code.

Comment: So, talking as an expert to a beginner in android development, when the confidence/skill grows with the programming language (not coming from a Java background either) You'd recommend using the OnClick method as a basic starter?

Comment: Yes, when choosing between two solutions where neither has significant advantages, then simplicity wins.

Answer (score 1):

**Point 1** - 
Creating it in code allow you to shield method access by making the method private, whereas doing it the xml way leads to exposure of the method.

**Point 2** - android:onClick is for API level 4 onwards, so if you're targeting < 1.6, then you can't use it.

Otherwise as per my understanding, these 2 are similar.

Answer (score 1):

It is really up to you, but keep in mind that `android:onClick="EventName"` will not work if you define it in an xml that will be inflated as part of a `Fragment` and you try to receive the button press on the `Fragment` itself. The `onClick` property only searches `Activities` for the method name you specified.

I would recommend you look into [`ButterKnife`](http://jakewharton.github.io/butterknife/)